# How to create email notification with login users on PHP an MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, email, authentication, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send an email notification when a page is visited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021183/how-to-send-an-email-notification-when-a-page-is-visited)

I just want to ask on how to create an email notification by login system. For example, if the user login on the system then the admin will get a mail from the system notifying that the user log in on the exact date and time that the user access the system.

The access like users are on the MYSQL Database

How can i call the users table using session and mail me through PHP system when he/she is login???

Can you help me here.

Comment: Do some homework. There are many examples available on google and the like. Have you tried anything?

Comment: PHP has a `mail()` function.. Perhaps you should look at [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: that is too much to explain here. go google and come back if you get really stuck

Comment: In the block where you're checking for successful login, add script to capture the date and time using date() and then send a email to your address. Simple as that

Answer (score 0):

```
$email = "self@email.com";
$subject = "New Membership";
$message = "your text here";
$header = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;\r\n";
mail($email, $subject, $message, $header);
```

You also have to have your email pop and smtp connections somewhere in MySql folder. Maybe someone else can help with that.

Comment: Yes i tried anything but no good results...i need to get the the data (user that access the login system) from the username data in my user database. But it's so hard to create such script. The final results must be the name of the user (username) will be on the mail message and it will send the other details like time and date to the admin email.can you pleas help

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using the MySQL database to retrieve information of the users when loging in.

```
           if($login_success){

            $email_to="admin@domain.com";
            $email_subject="A user logged in to the system";
            $email_from='system_info@domain.com';

            $email_message = "Following user has logged in to the system at ".$time."\n\n";

            $email_message .= "Name  : ".$name."\n\n";
            $email_message .= "Email  : ".$email."\n\n";
            $email_message .= "User ID: ".$user_id."\n\n";


            $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
            'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
            @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
        }
```

Time of the login can be calculated - `$time= date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');`

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes i tried anything but no good results...i need to get the the data (user that access the login system) from the username data in my user database. But it's so hard to create such script. The final results must be the name of the user (username) will be on the mail message and it will send the other details like time and date to the admin email.can you pleas help